# $\displaystyle f: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ is analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

let $\displaystyle f: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ be an analytic function. For $z = x + iy$, let $u, v: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be such that
$u(x,y) = \Re f(z)$ and $v(x,y) = \Im f(z)$. Which of the following are correct?

1.∂2u∂x2+∂2u∂y2 = 0

2.∂2v∂x2+∂2v∂y2 = 0

3.∂2u∂x∂y-∂2u∂y∂x = 0

4 ∂2v∂x∂y+∂2v∂y∂x = 0

[image]

now since $f$ is given as analytic function,  $u$ and $v$ must be harmonic function, so option 1 and 2 are correct. Further as C-R equation is satisfied by u and v, using C-R equation option 3 can be obtained and option 4 is incorrect. Am i right?
But in original answer key only 1st and 3rd are shown as correct option, i am wondering why option 2 is not there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why Option 2 isn't there as I didn't author the textbook! However, if I did author the textbook, then I'd put it there because as you correctly point out, the real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are always real harmonic functions.

Now, I'm not sure the Cauchy-Riemann equations come into the picture. Option 3 just says that the mixed partial derivatives of $u$ are equal. That's always going to be the case for any $C^2$ function. Thankfully, in our case, $u$ is real harmonic and, in particular, $C^{\infty}$ so Option 3 is satisfied. In light of this, can you see why Option 4 must fail in general?

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you Amitesh. option 4 is incorrect because mixed partial derivatives of v are also equal.

Comment: @AlkaGoyal I agree!